# presentation layer to go with apache torque

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, apache-torque

I'm planning on using Apache torque as my object-relational mapper (ORM), and I was wondering if anybody has any suggestions around what framework to use for presentation layer with torque. maybe Spring?

I don't know if this helps, but my application is basically going to be bunch of forms to input data and based on that data, I'll generate reports in form of a graph or chart.

Comment: What made you decide to go with Torque rather than a more commonly used ORM like Hibernate?

Comment: That's just what I was thinking Mark.

Comment: Last release of Torque was February 2008. Madness to pick this for a green-field development.

Comment: Fourth that... Hibernate, JPA, maybe iBatis, or possibly JDO (I thought this was dead but google used it for google app, so it's not).

Comment: Ooh, JDO, now there's a blast from the (recent) past.

Comment: I've used hibernate before, and just wanted to try something new. Torque seemed like a nice framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is web-based then CSS/XHTML/JQuery & Spring MVC has always worked out great for me, otherwise, if it's thick-client, Swing.

Incidentally, if you get you 'separation-of-concerns' right your choice of ORM should have no impact what presentation layer you use.

I'd also advise using Hibernate rather than Torque, it is, from my perspective at least, practically a defacto standard nowadays, which translates into many more production hours and a lot of people to help when you run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

[Turbine](http://turbine.apache.org/) is a servlet framework that integrates with Torque (Torque was originally part of Turbine). It can use either Velocity or JSP as its presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing charts and want them to be interactive, often combining Jersey/REST with Flex and/or jQuery charting libs (sparklines are cool) charts works well.  As previously mentioned, Spring MVC is good, as is Struts 2 for flat pages.